# Why does Google Chrome not show base64 encoded images?

Tags: image, google-chrome, base64

Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera accept following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.minus
{
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwALAIABAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAALAAsAAAIUhI8Wy6zdHlxyqnTBdHqHCoERlhQAOw");
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="minus">
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome (Version 19.0.1084.56) does not. Why?

Answer (score 7):

This is a bug in Chrome, see [bug #105725](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=105725). The base64-string has to be padded. The following solution works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/TunfH/ (I have added `==` at the end).

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.minus
{
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwALAIABAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAALAAsAAAIUhI8Wy6zdHlxyqnTBdHqHCoERlhQAOw==");
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="minus"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your base64 data is invalid, I believe you meant

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwALAIABAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAALAAsAAAIUhI8Wy6zdHlxyqnTBdHqHCoERlhQAOw==
```

Which seems to work just fine in Chrome and Firefox [ what I have access to ]

I am guessing that Chrome has a slightly more strict base64 implementation and requires the padding.

Comment: All b64 requires padding

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you have "//" which you need to "escape" in order to avoid the err_invalid_url warning you see in the console

So take your:

```
R0lGODlhCwALAIABAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAALAAsAAAIUhI8Wy6zdHlxyqnTBdHqHCoERlhQAOw
```

And convert it to

```
R0lGODlhCwALAIABAAAAAP/%0a/%0a/yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAALAAsAAAIUhI8Wy6zdHlxyqnTBdHqHCoERlhQAOw
```

And the it will show properly

The same solution should be used if the image starts with a "/" replace it with "%0a/"

Comment: Hi, your answer is confusing because the encoding above has three forward-slash characters, i.e. '/', but it looks like you have only replaced two of the slashes with '%0a/'. Am I missing something? Also what character does '%0a' encode to? Isn't that a line-feed? Why does a line-feed escape a forward slash? If that is something specific to URL encodings perhaps you could mention a reference. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielBradley this post is old, the Chrome version mentioned is old as well.. only two %0a were needed back then, they prevented the "//" detection from occurring which Chrome thought was resource being referenced (URI)

Answer (score -1):

I added the ...;charset=utf-8;base64, .... to one of my files and that did the trick for me, just thought I would share what happened to work for me with chrome, I knew I added the image file to my code but it wasn't showing on my client's computer, found out it was a chrome issue and adding the charset solved my issues.

Comment: Can you please provide an actual example of the HTML that shows where you put that string.