# base64 image not working in google chrome but works in firefox

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, firefox

why does this work in firefox but not in google chrome??

```
data:jpg;base64,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
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067472/why-does-google-chrome-not-show-base64-encoded-images

Comment: You should post a working demo in for example jsbin.com.

Comment: Your content-type is invalid.

Comment: what is it invalid? the original image is a jpg?

see: http://www.merdb.co/files/movie/2749128_The_Prince.jpg

Comment: nvm thanks i found the problem,

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem using this:

```
data:image/jpg;base64
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: You need to provide the complete solution, this answer doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @Candy I would argue that this is technically an answer, since it presents a solution to the problem in the question. It's not a particularly good answer, however, since it doesn't explain *why* this fixes the problem. On inspection, it appears the content type was invalid, as SLaks pointed out in a comment.